# Adding Z-Index to a drop down that is within a overflow container

Tags: html, css

I have a css drop down menu at the end of a div that I need to add a z-index to so it will appear above all other content on the page. The dropdown is working fine, but Im unsure of where to add the z-index. Ive gone through it many times in chrome's inspector and I cannot change the order of the layer.

Here is my html:

```
 <div id="main_view_wrapper">
   <div id="main_view">
    <div class="show">
      <ul><li class="accept">Accept</li>
       <li class="decline">
       Decline
        <ul>
         <li class="topdropdown"><a href="#" class="decline><div class="textdrop">Drop down Menu 1</a></div></li>
         <li class="bottomdropdown"><a href="#" class="decline"><div class="textdrop">Drop down menu 2</div></a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

and here is all of my CSS:

```
#main_view_wrapper{
    width: 615px;
    height: 385px;
    background: #474747;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#main_view{
  width: 560px;
  height: 230px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.show{
  width: 560px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #404040;
  text-align: top;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;

}

  ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;  
}

ul li.accept {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background: #ef8200;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li.decline {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  background: #007fc2;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.textdrop{
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #006699;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #111;;
  color: #fff;

}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li.dropdown { 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  background-color: #007fc2;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
ul li ul li.dropdown a {  
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul li.topdropdown {  
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  background-color: #007fc2;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
ul li ul li.topdropdown a { 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  ul li ul li:hover { 
  background: #888; 
  ul li:hover ul 
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li ul li.bottomdropdown {
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  background-color: #007fc2;
  left: -180px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
ul li ul li.bottomdropdown a {  
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is an image showing the menu dropping behind the bottom of the main_view DIV:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the z-index at all. You have your dropdown set to "visibility:hidden" and "display:none" but nothing making it show up on hover. You need to add -

```
ul li.decline:hover ul  { 
    display: block; 
}
```

and remove the visibility property, it's unnecessary. here's a fiddle:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/bY5Ph/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. It did bring it up above the rows beneath it, but it is still tucked below the bottom of the main_view DIV that has the vertical scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, it's above everything. What is it below exactly? It's inside of the main_view DIV which has an overflow of hidden which will make everything that is inside of it which goes outside of it's boundaries disappear at it's boundaries.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to my post. You can see the menu dropping below the bottom of the DIV. I have four menu items. Ideally I want the menu above all other content and to the right over the scrollbar.Is there any way to have the vertical scrollbar with a hidden overflow?

Comment: Well I can see you're using some sort of custom scroller, I can't re-create what you're looking to do. Can you post a demo on JS fiddle or something please?

Comment: No, its just a styled scrollbar; nothing special - here is the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/LPcD3/5/  youll need to expand the results section to see the whole issue. I need the menu to go over the scrollbar and the blue area next to it. If that cannot happen at least have it displayed over the div it is in.

Comment: Here is an update to your demo but if you have the main container set to overflow:auto the dropdown will not go out of it, that's the nature of that property. http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/LPcD3/13/

Answer (score 0):

you have another div with z-index?

Another suggestion, try the z-index at `<li class="decline">` or even in `<div id="main_view">`

Try with an z-index larger, like z-index: 100

Comment: I did, but it was in the top menu I removed the z-index there and tried it in behind places you suggested, but the menu is still tucked away behind the main_view_wrapper